# Problem whith automigration Loopback 3 en oracle datasource

Tags: node.js, oracle, session, loopback

PS E:\PROJECT\LOOPBACK\meetupz> node server/bin/automigration.js

CODE:

```
 var app = require('../server');
    // this loads the accountDb configuration in ~/server/datasources.json
    var dataSource = app.dataSources.db;

    dataSource.automigrate('User', function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      dataSource.disconnect();
    });

    // this automigrates the model
    dataSource.automigrate('meetup', function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      dataSource.disconnect();
    });
```

RESULT:

> Unhandled rejection Error: ORA-24422: error occurred while trying to
>   destroy the Session

Please help

Comment: Seems like there are timing issues here. I don't use Loopback, but are you sure this is written correctly? What did you base your code on? If you don't have an error after migrating 'User', then you'll have closed the dataSource which would cause other issues.

Comment: Yes,  the code is is writen correctly.I use the migration with the command: "node server/bin/automigration.js".
The table is correctly created in the schema in oracle but when i try to call an api , it return that "Table or  View does not exist in the schema".
I think that there are some Pool or session witch is locked.

Comment: The error you display in your initial question is "ORA-24422: error occurred while trying to destroy the Session", but now you're saying it's "Table or view does not exist". Which is it?

Comment: "ORA-24422: error occurred while trying to destroy the Session" when i try to use automigration on Oracle.
 After that, i can't do anything.Javascript code can't access Table on Oracle.

Comment: Earlier you said, "Yes, the code is is writen correctly." How do you know this? What did you use as a guide?

Comment: Also, please try commenting out these lines "dataSource.disconnect();"

Comment: Yes i say that the code is writen correctly because the code is from loopback official guide.The difference is that the loopback guide use "Mongodb" and "Mysql" as datasource.We use Oracle as database at work.

Comment: Please provide a link to the doc/code that you used.

Comment: this is the github link: https://github.com/jrandria/loopback_and_oracle.git

The Loopback 3 guide for automigration:
    https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Implementing-auto-migration.html

and

    https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-a-database-schema-from-models.html

Thanks Mister Dan McGhan :)

Comment: The example in the following link passes an array of tables to automigrate and then calls disconnect a single time in the callback. https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-a-database-schema-from-models.html Can you do that?

Comment: The first time i use automigration of my table , it's work correctly . But when i modify propriety and automigrate again, that's where the problem started.

Comment: Hey it's works .

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad it's working. I'll add an answer to your question for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to make a single call to `automigrate` and disconnect once. https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-a-database-schema-from-models.html